# Could not capture 401 errors in AngularJS 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, authentication, observable

I have been working with an AngularJs2 app for the past week. This app has a service called 'CabBookingService' and it makes an http get() call to get data from the backend. The backend is REST based and is authenticated using a Spring security OAuth2 implementation.

```
@Injectable()
export class CabBookingService {


private accessToken, bookingsUrl, bookings;

constructor(private _logger: Logger, private _http: Http) {
    this.accessToken = localStorage.getItem('cabservice_access_token');
    this.bookingsUrl = "http://52.3.51.119:8081/dynamo-server/dynamo/api/cabservice/bookings/list/submitted?access_token=" + this.accessToken;
}

getCabBookings() {
    this._logger.log("Getting Cab Bookings ...accessToken, bookingsUrl = " + this.accessToken + "," + this.bookingsUrl);

    return this._http.get(this.bookingsUrl)
        .map(res => {
            this._logger.log("response status = " + res.status);
            return <CabBooking[]> res.json().cabBooking;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error("Error occured in getting bookings...response: type, ok, url, status, headers:  " + error.type + ", " + error.ok + ", " +
        error.url + ", " + error.status + ", " + JSON.stringify(error.headers));
    return Observable.throw(error.json().headers || 'Server error');
}
}
```

As shown in the code, the service uses a token stored in browser local storage in the HTTP request. When the token is valid, I get data which I handle in the Angular component below.

```
this._cabBookingService.getCabBookings()
        .subscribe(
            bookings => {
                this.bookings = bookings;
                this._logger.log("Bookings => " + JSON.stringify(this.bookings));
            },
            err => {
                this._logger.log("Error while accessing cab bookings...error, JSONed = " + err.status + "," + JSON.stringify(err));
            },
            () => console.log('Bookings Fetched!');
            );
```

When the token is expired and when I invoke the service to get data, the server throws a 401 error. This is confirmed by looking at the Chrome browser developer tools Network tab.

[Chrome browser developer tab showing 401 error while using Angular HTTP Get. The console message that follows shows 200 instead of 401.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnnv5.png)

The problem I have is that I am not able to capture this 401 error. When I log the error in handleError() method, I get the following:

```
Error occured in getting bookings...response: type, ok, url, status, headers:  3, undefined, null, 200, "[]"
```

That is, the log shows a 200 HTTP code instead of 401. Please let me know if I need to do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Check the network log for HTTP methods. If you are writing a HTML5 app then allow 'option' in your server for [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). For example, you can add this to your PHP server page.

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
?>
```